# Как вывести список названий колонок, сумма элементов которых больше 3?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, анализ-данных

Как вывести список колонок, сумма элементов которых больше 3?

Пока что в качестве вывода имею список из True/False:

```
res = df_train[df_train.columns].sum()>3
df_train = list(res)
df_train
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Пример:

```
In [43]: df
Out[43]:
   a  b  c
0  1  0  2
1  2  1  2
2  2  1  2

In [44]: df.columns[df.sum() > 3].to_list()
Out[44]: ['a', 'c']
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы.

Comment: Ой, работает. А у меня сначала что-то так не работало, пришлось длинное какое-то решение фигачить )

Answer (score 3):

Как-то так, например, если нужен список таких колонок:

```
print(list(df_train.loc[:,df_train.sum() > 3].columns))
```

А если нужны данные в этих колонках, то в общем просто через `.loc`:

```
df_train.loc[:,df_train.sum() > 3]
```